# what is the derivative of this function

Tags: derivatives

I need help in this following question. I have tried many attempts but really confused on how to solve it. Therefore, i would appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks allot

$$f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{e^{x^2 + 2}}$$

Answer (score 7):

$$f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{e^{x^2 + 2}}$$

We use the quotient rule: $$f(x) = \dfrac {g(x)}{h(x)} \implies f'(x) = \dfrac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

Here, $$g(x) = \ln x \implies g'(x) = \dfrac 1x$$ $$h(x) = e^{x^2 + 2} \implies h'(x) = 2x\cdot e^{x^2 + 2}$$

Note we need the chain rule for finding $h'(x)$.

Can you take it from here? You'll be able to simplify once you "plug into" the formula given by the quotient rule.

> $$\dfrac{\frac 1x \cdot e^{x^2 + 2} - \ln x(2xe^{x^2+ 2})}{(e^{x^2 + 2})^2} = \dfrac{e^{x^2 + 2}\Big(\frac 1x - 2x\ln x\Big)}{e^{2(x^2 + 2)}} = \dfrac{1- 2x^2 \ln x}{xe^{x^2 + 2}}$$

Comment: For my friends. :-)

Comment: @B.S. what do you mean? haha sorry

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Rewrite the function as:

$$f(x) = \ln x e^{-x^2-2}$$

Now, use the product rule to find the result.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} ( uv) = v \dfrac{du}{dx} + u \dfrac{dv}{dx}$$

**Spoiler**

> f'(x) = $-2e^{-x^2-2}~x~\ln x + \dfrac{e^{-x^2-2}}{x}$

Of course, you could have also just used the quotient and should give that a go!

Comment: @B.S.: Thank you my friend and have a wonderful day! :-) Neat whirlpool!

Comment: @amWhy: Ditto + 1

Comment: Here we both are on Christmas Eve day, and where are we? ;-) Time to roll out the list: $$\text{Top $\,10\,$ reasons: How you know if you're a MSE addict!}$$ (In time for New Year's Resolutions!)

Comment: Ditto, here. We'll have to be sure to connect for a "virtual toast" to the holidays!

Comment: @amWhy: Sounds swell and it is not even POETS Day! :-)

Answer (score 2):

another occasionally useful device is to rewrite as:
$$(e^{x^2 + 2})f(x) = ln \;x$$ and use the product rule on the LHS to get:
$$(2xe^{x^2+2})f(x) + (e^{x^2 + 2})f'(x) = \frac 1x
$$ so
$$ f'(x) = (\frac1x -2x \;ln \;x)(e^{x^2 + 2})^{-1}
$$

Comment: Nice approach +1

Comment: thx, Amzoti. appreciate a bit of kindness on here. my ankles are quite sore from bites after only a few weeks!